# Describing the Dimensions of an Antenna using Latex

Tags: dimensions

I have been trying to insert the table of dimensions of an antenna in a latex code. I used the code

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l | l | l | l | l}
Reference Number & BW (GhHz) & Antenna size (mm3) & Gain & Notched Bands (GHz) \\
\hline
[20] & 2.3-13.75  & 39*39*1 pt 6 & 1 pt 4-46 & 2 pt 25-3.75
5.08-5.9
7.06-7.95
 \\
[21] & 3.11-13.15 & 28*52*1.6 & 1.53-4.05 & 5.1-5.92 \\
[22] & 2.8-14 & 27*36*1.6 & N/A & 3.26-3.9
4.35-5.05
5.5-6.35
7.95-9.35
 \\
Current Work & 3.1 – 17 & 24*28*1.6 & 4.5-8 & 3.2-3.9
7.2-8.5

\end{tabular}
\caption{Comparison of the suggested antenna to antennas in previous litrature}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

but the error:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l | l | l | l | l}
Reference Number & BW (GhHz) & Antenna size (mm3) & Gain & Notched Bands (GHz) \\
\hline
[20] & 2.3-13.75  & 39*39*1 pt 6 & 1 pt 4-46 & 2 pt 25-3.75
5.08-5.9
7.06-7.95
 \\
[21] & 3.11-13.15 & 28*52*1.6 & 1.53-4.05 & 5.1-5.92 \\
[22] & 2.8-14 & 27*36*1.6 & N/A & 3.26-3.9
4.35-5.05
5.5-6.35
7.95-9.35
 \\
Current Work & 3.1 – 17 & 24*28*1.6 & 4.5-8 & 3.2-3.9
7.2-8.5

\end{tabular}
\caption{Comparison of the suggested antenna to antennas in previous litrature}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

kept showing. How can I simply insert the dimension of an item in a table.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE and Happy New Year! You need to enclose `[20]`, `[21]` and `[22]` in curly braces :  `{[20]}`, `{[21]}` and `{[22]}`.

Comment: The point being that a number in square brackets immediately after `\hline` is picked up as an optional argument, which has to be a dimension. Using braces as suggested by @Zarko will prevent this.

Comment: There is also `$\[...\]$` and `$\leftbracket ... \rightbracket$`.

Answer (score 0):

See if the following MWE with your table is acceptable to you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{l | l | l | l | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{9em}}
    \hline
\makecell{Reference\\ Number}
        & \makecell{BW\\(GHz)}
                        & \makecell{Antenna\\ size (mm)}
                                    & \makecell{Gain\\ (dB)}
                                                & \makecell{Notched\\ Bands (GHz)}   \\
    \hline
{[20]}  & 2.3-13.75     & 39*39*1   & 4-46      & 25-3.75 5.08-5.9 7.06-7.95                \\
{[21]}  & 3.11-13.15    & 28*52*1.6 & 1.53-4.05 & 5.1-5.92                                  \\
{[22]}  & 2.8-14        & 27*36*1.6 & N/A       & 3.26-3.9 4.35-5.05 5.5-6.35 7.95-9.35     \\
Current Work & 3.1–17   & 24*28*1.6 & 4.5-8     & 3.2-3.9 7.2-8.5                           \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Comparison of the suggested antenna to antennas in previous literature}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate tex area borders)